# Index Out Of Bound exception in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, exception

I'm trying to load my pictures into dynamically created pictureboxes. The pictures will be retrieved from a mysql server which is located on my local network. I've been able to get one picture in a picturebox by changing the query to pick only 1 id. so I know it works with one at the time.

**Code:**

```
private void ass_wijzig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string query = "Select Image From Product";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
       // MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Image");
        int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;
        DataRow myrow;
        byte[] mydata = new byte[0];
        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
             myrow= ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i];
            // var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["Image"]);
             mydata = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["Image"]);
             Stream[] str = new MemoryStream[i];
             str[i] = new MemoryStream(mydata);
             PictureBox[] pbx = new PictureBox[i];
             pbx[i] = new PictureBox();
             pbx[i].Size = new Size(150, 150);
             pbx[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
             pbx[i].Image = Image.FromStream(str[i]);
             pbx[i].Visible = true;
             pbx[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
             x += pbx[i].Location.X + pbx[i].Width;
             this.Controls.Add(pbx[i]);
        }
```

The exception is thrown at `Stream[] str = new MemoryStream[i];`
I would be honored if somebody knew the problem,

Thanks in advance

Comment: you shouldn't assume the upper bound of `i`.

Comment: This piece of code is so riddled with weird statements, you should probably take it apart into different blocks: read byte[]s from database, transform byte[] to stream, create image from stream, create picturebox from image. As it is, it's a mess of superfluous code. Drop the dataadapter/datatable and use a simple datareader. Drop all arrays. You don't need them. Loop over your datareader and create one picturebox each loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that arrays are 0-indexed.

```
Stream[] str = new MemoryStream[i];
```

Creates an array of length i, so the valid indices are 0 ... i - 1.

Then you do:

```
str[i] = new MemoryStream(mydata);
```

Which tries to access index i, which is invalid.

Looking at your code, I'm not sure why you're using an array here at all instead of a normal variable. Just do:

```
Stream str = new MemoryStream(myData);
```

instead.

Comment: I removed the array from the stream, but how can i get the picturebox to work? now they are out of bound

Comment: @user3697100: it looks like the same issue there. Change the picture box array to a simple PictureBox variable.